# "Timeout in polling result file" error when executing a Dataflow flex-template job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I've tried a lot of different things found online, but I'm still unable to solve the below timeout error:

```
2021-11-27T14:51:21.844520452ZTimeout in polling result file: gs://...
```

when submitting a Dataflow flex-template job. It goes into `Queued` state and after `14 mins {x} secs` goes to `Failed` state with the above log message. My `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY test-beam.py .

# Do not include `apache-beam` in requirements.txt
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/test-beam.py"

# Setting Proxy
ENV http_proxy=http://proxy-web.{company_name}.com:80 \
    https_proxy=http://proxy-web.{company_name}.com:80 \
    no_proxy=127.0.0.1,localhost,.{company_name}.com,{company_name}.com,.googleapis.com

# Company Cert
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl http://{company_name}.com/pki/{company_name}%20Issuing%20CA.pem -o - | tr -d '\r' > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{company_name}.crt \
    && curl http://{company_name}.com/pki/{company_name}%20Root%20CA.pem -o - | tr -d '\r' > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{company_name}-root.crt \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apt-get remove -y --purge curl \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set pip config to point to Company Cert
RUN pip config set global.cert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Install apache-beam and other dependencies to launch the pipeline
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]==2.32.0 \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    # Download the requirements to s7peed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE

# Since we already downloaded all the dependencies, there's no need to rebuild everything.
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True

ENV http_proxy= \
    https_proxy= \
    no_proxy=

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]
```

And `requirements.py`:

```
numpy
setuptools
scipy
wavefile
```

I know my Python script used above `test-beam.py` works as it executes successfully locally using a `DirectRunner`.

I have gone through many SO posts and GCP's own troubleshooting guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#python) aimed at this error, however to no success. As you can see from my `Dockerfile`, I have done the following in it:

1. Installing `apache-beam[gcp]` separately and not including it in my `requirements.txt` file.
2. Pre-downloading all dependencies using `pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE`.
3. Setting `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/google/dataflow/python_template_launcher"]` explicitly as it seems this is not set in the base image `gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base` as found by executing `docker inspect` on it (am I correct about this?).
4. Unsetting company proxy at the end as it seems to be the cause of timeout issues seen in job logs from previous runs.

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?